# HtmlUnit - Selecting Forms, CheckBoxes, TextFields, and Submit Buttons

Tags: java, forms, groovy, checkbox, htmlunit

I have been messing around with HtmlUnit for a little bit and particularly this website because it has quite a few features that I wanted to get used to. I have posted about it before but that was mainly for grabbing information off the site which ended up successful. Now I am wanting to fill in a form and submit it.

**Current Test Code:**

```
def url = "http://www.hidemyass.com/proxy-list/"


client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3)
client.javaScriptEnabled = false

page = client.getPage(url)
form = page.getFormByName("proxyform")

//get portInputField and set value
portField = form.getInputByName("p")
portField.setValueAttribute("80")

//select checkbox 1 & 2 from anonymity level
//click "Update Results"
//get new page url
//grab information
//save
```

The section commented out is where I am unsure of what to do. I went ahead and attempted but would like to ask for input on what I should be doing.

**Attempt:**

```
def url = "http://www.hidemyass.com/proxy-list/"

page = client.getPage(url)

portField = page.getHtmlElementById("ports").setValueAttribute("80")

submitButton = page.getByXPath("/html/body//form//input[@type='image']")
page2 = submitButton.get(0).click()

println page2
```

The snippet above prints out: **HtmlPage(http://www.hidemyass.com/proxy-list/search-1)@17168934**

I'm looking to get a new page where I can then parse the information from the search. Any ideas?

I don't believe the language I am using should make too much of a difference; however, I am using Groovy.

**EDIT**

I managed to get what I wanted but it returns like so:

```
HtmlPage(http://www.hidemyass.com/proxy-list/search-1)@23713629
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><td>109.123.00.00</td>
```

Is there a way to get only the information that I'm looking for : `<td>109.123.00.00</td>` or do I just need to strip the info from it manually?

**EDIT**

.asText() solved my issue, but gave quite a few warnings regarding the CSS. Should I be worried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to get only the
>   information that I'm looking for :
>   109.123.00.00 or do I just
>   need to strip the info from it
>   manually?

This should work:

```
def td = page2.getElementByName("td")
assert td.textContent == "109.123.00.00"
```

See the JavaDoc for [HtmlPage](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlPage.html) for other ways to extract information from a page. Don't parse the page manually.

Side note: Since you are already using Groovy, you could also have a look at [Geb](http://geb.codehaus.org), a popular Groovy-based web automation and testing tool that's more convenient to use than HtmlUnit.

Comment: lol I had an undeclared variable which was throwing off my code. (I went back and edited it a few too many times and didn't realized I removed it. I have edited the question as a final part of it. If you have the chance to comment on that, I would appreciate it. Also thanks for mentioning `Geb` I'll check into it, although I'm just starting to get comfortable with HtmlUnit a bit.